# Nginx allow files but not folders to be accessed

Tags: nginx, server, ubuntu-18.04

In nginx I'm looking to allow direct access to files but not the folder they are in..

Example

If I go to

http://mysite:43467/mystuff/docs/file1.doc

I will see the file perfect this is what I want

But

If I go to

http://mysite:43467/mystuff/docs/

Or
http://mysite:43467/mystuff/

I want to get a 404 not found error. If either of these are used so only the full address is the accessible

I want only the direct file / file address accessible.

Is this possible

Thanks

Update

Working example found on the net

http://lightspeed.sytes.net:25461/movie/mvcXZMLIYO/DQq0ilPnDz/12089.mp4
This works

But if u try access

http://lightspeed.sytes.net:25461/movie/

For example access denied

I am looking this sort of thing

Comment: This question needs more context. What behavior do you expect instead of the 404?
If you want to show a directory index you can <code>autoindex on;</code>, if you want to serve a default file, then have a look at try-files

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried and the behaviour it's currently displaying?

Comment: I haven't I've seen it done before just unsure how to go about doing it

Comment: Added working examples of what I'm looking for

Comment: Anyone any ideas I'm lost??